# ¿Porque mi funcion no espera a que se recorra las condicinales y despues hace el return?

Tags: java, android-studio, api, android-volley

Tengo tiempo si programar en java y lo estoy retomando creando una app en la que hace un una peticion a una API que cree en express y funciona correctamente el problema es que la funcion hace el return sin esperar la respuesta del servidor

```
public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, JSONObject postRequestBody){

    returnResult = "";

    // In case that the elemenet required are empty return an "No Data Provided"

    if (requestURL.equals("") || postRequestBody.length() == 0){

        returnResult = "No Data Provided";

    }

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestURL, postRequestBody, response -> {

        // In case there is a response we return

        returnResult = response.toString();
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest",response.toString());

    }, error -> {

        // In case there is an error we return

        if (String.valueOf(error).equals("")){
            returnResult = error.toString();
        }

    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    return returnResult;

}
```

Lo que quiero es que una vez que se tenga el response se guarde en la variable returnResult y despues haga el return.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: No soy experto en Java pero me parece que el problema tiene que ver con funciones asincrónicas. La función `sendPostRequest` no espera a que se ejecute el callback del objeto `JsonObjectRequest`

Comment: Claro ese es el problema no se como hacerlo, en javascript simplemente lo hago await pero en java no se como. ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Tengo entendido que Java no tiene ningún equivalente a async / await. Me parece que en vez de retornar la variable `returnResult`, la función `sendPostRequest` debería recibir un callback y llamarlo desde el callback de `JsonObjectRequest`.

Comment: Pero tal vez alguien con más conocimiento de Java pueda proporcionar una solución más elegante

Comment: Bueno hermano tenias toda la razon solo tenia que agregar un callback muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que en este caso **la petición es un proceso Asyncronico, lo ideal es que al obtener la respuesta dentro de `onResponse()`, uses el valor del resultado y puedas llamar el siguiente proceso**.

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestURL, postRequestBody, response -> {

        returnResult = response.toString();
        //*Se obtiene resultado, llama función para realizar el siguiente proceso.


    }, error -> {

        // Ocurrió un error.

    });
```

---

Si aún deseas obtener la respuesta al llamar un método que realice la petición , puedes hacer uso de una `interface` usando `VolleyCallback`, revisa :

[Devolver datos de respuesta de la función "onResponse" en Volley Library](https://mobikul.com/how-to-send-json-post-request-using-volley-rest-api/)

Creas una interface:

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccessResponse(String result);
}
```

esta interface la usas dentro del método `onResponse()` :

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(String Response) {
        callback.onSuccessResponse(Response);
    }
```